# Area of a triangle when two sides and an angle is given

Tags: triangles

Can you find the area of a triangle if it's 2 sides are given and the angle formed by these sides are given?

Comment: https://www.mathopenref.com/triangleareasas.html

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will hep you understand how best to form questions and answers. The lingua franca for formulation is [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 2):

For completeness , I prove that the area equals **$\frac{1}{2}ab\sin c$**
.Let the sides of known measures be $AB$ and $AC$ . Let the known angle be $\angle BAC$
[image]

Draw perpendicular $CD$ to $AB$ . Then , the area = $$\frac{1}{2}bh=\frac{1}{2}AB\cdot CD=\frac{1}{2}AB\cdot (AC\cdot \sin \angle CAB) $$

Comment: Nice answer, certainly not a lazy one like mine. \cdot $( \ \cdot  \ ) $ might help your formatting, though you can choose to ignore this.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback ! I didn’t know this...

Comment: No problem, I am always glad to help. Be sure to check out https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference for more tips on $\LaTeX$

Answer (score 1):

Use that $$A=\frac{1}{2}ab\sin(\gamma)$$ etc

Answer (score 1):

Yes.
$$A=\frac 12ab\sin \theta$$

Comment: If this doesn't answer the question, I don't know what will. Should I provide more details?